# Struts2 Tags Error With struts-convention-plugin

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags, struts2-convention-plugin

I've implemented REST into existing non-Restful Struts application and REST module work normally. The trouble is some button in the web page with struts-tags and other taglib make error

> org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean | Could not open template
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper.getUriFromActionMapping(PrefixBasedActionMapper.java:117)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.FormButton.evaluateExtraParams(FormButton.java:83)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.Submit.evaluateExtraParams(Submit.java:86)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:902)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.Submit.evaluateParams(Submit.java:82)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean.start(ClosingUIBean.java:55)
>       at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:53)

I have found the trouble, it because attribut action inside submit button

```
<s:submit value="Button" action="my-action-here"/>
```

I can replace attribut action with onClick like this

```
<input type="button" value="Button" onClick="someFunction()"/>

function someFunction(){
var params = 'line to add parameter'
window.location.href="<s:url action='my-action'/>"+params;
}
```

to execute the action, but there are 2504 page of jsp file and if i need to check all of them, it too much trouble. Is there any easier way to resolve it?

Comment: What is the implementation `onClick` function which makes your `submit` button work?!

Comment: Did you write `action` attribute in all of the 2504 jsp?

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi i add this line on function window.location.href='<s:url action="my-action"/>'

Comment: @RomanC not all of jsp, but i need to check all of it

Comment: The `window.location` change the browser url but did not submit the form and you do not have you data at the server, are you sure that it is working as you expect ?! By the way the `s:url` can not be used in `s:submit` in this way. you will face jsp compile error

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi sorry, it's my fault i replace s:submit into input, cause it's not a form that i want to submit, but some parameters from its form.

Comment: Why are you using `type="button"`, it doesn't work with action attribute.

Comment: Which version of S2 are you using?